# Lyx bibliography displaying section number

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, back-referencing

I am using LyX to write my thesis. I am using a BibTeX Generated Bibliography (generated in Jabref) which works fine. I just have one problem, in the actual PDF, the Bibliography section after each reference, the section where that reference was cited is printed out, for example:

```
[1] R. Budwig, “Refractive index matching methods for liquid flow investigations,” Experiments in Fluids, vol. 17, no. 5, pp. 350–355, 1994. 2.7.4
```

Where "2.7.4" is the section where this reference is cited.

Is this related to my overall master style file, or is it just a simple setting in LyX that I can disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the back references are inserted by package `backref`. Either it is loaded
explicitly or it is loaded by package `hyperref` via options `backref` or `pagebackref`.
I am not familiar with `Lyx`, but at least you have some hints, what needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem, in my Latex Preambles i had backref as one of the packages to use. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this problem easily in lyx by going to: `document -> settings -> PDF Properites` and then unchecking the "Use Hyperref Support."

If I kept the `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble, doing the above would just get rid of hyperlinks from the bibliography entries.  If I got rid of `\usepackage{hyperref}`, doing the above would eliminate all hyperlinks throughout the document.

Comment: It's not clear that this actually answers the question. The OP is interested in just eliminating the back references in the bibliography, not all hyperlinks in the document.

Comment: "would just get rid of hyperlinks from the bibliography entries." In other words -- it gets rid of backrefs in the bibliography.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so the references contain the page numbers (in order) that the reference appears on?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the section numbers from the bibliography as follows:

Document -> PDF Properties -> Hyperlinks -> Backreferences -> Off

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks (+1). By the way the correct chain is Document -> Settings... -> PDF Properties Hyperlinks -> Backreferences -> Off