# BibLaTeX in LyX 2.1.0 with MiKTex on Windows 7: ! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'backref'

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx, citing

I took the `tex` code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174883/4821) and imported to `LyX 2.1.0` to use `BibLaTeX` with `MiKTeX` on `Windows 7`. But I'm getting the following error:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'backref'.
```

The problem persists even after updating the packages. I wonder how to figure out this problem. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

The same code works fine in `tex` but after importing to `LyX 2.1.0` it throws the error. Might be in the back-end `LyX 2.1.0` using `backref` package too.

I also tried

> Tools > Preferences > Output > LaTeX > Bibliography generation > Processor > Biber

but without any success.

Comment: Don't use the `backref` package with `biblatex`. Use the `backref` option biblatex has.

Comment: Or do you use the exact same code as in the link?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the exact code given in the link.

Comment: I've retracted my answer, as it seems that there is more going on than meets the eye.  *Something* is loading the `backref` package, it would appear.  `biblatex` includes a check/call with `\@ifpackageloaded{backref}`, and that is what is triggering the error, even if you haven't loaded it explicitly... Now, the question becomes, What could cause that?

Comment: It seems that LyX is by default loading `backref`, try `Document > Settings > PDF Properties > Backreferences > Off` and have a look here [Lyx bibliography displaying section number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68447/35864) (the answer discussed there might not be what you want). This question [How to surpress pagenumbers in bibliography section in LyX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81987/35864) seems to be almost identical and even has a nice screenshot (in German though) on what you have to do.

Comment: Did any of the answers I linked to help?

Comment: In `LyX 2.1.0` I tried `Document > Settings > PDF Properties` and unchecked `Use Hyperref Support`. This compiled the file but doesn't show `bibliography` and show citation with only `bibtex key`.

Comment: `biblatex` uses `biber` by default, so do Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, and select `biber` as *Processor*.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT.. This does the trick in `LyX`. Could you change your comment to answer. Please also guide me how to get this work with `TexnicCenter` and `TexStudio`.

Comment: If you mean running `biber`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Did only turning back-references off not work, or is there any other reason why you decided to entirely turn off the `hyperref` support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tools > Preferences > Output > LaTeX > Bibliography generation > Processor > Biber

and

> Document > Settings > Bibliography

and selecting `biber` and *Processor* did the trick in `LyX 2.1.0`.

Comment: You are aware that this doesn't answer the question as it stands? The problem that the question is about was answered by @moewe's comment about turning off backreferences in the Document settings. You have just answered the *new* problem that occurred afterwards,  which is not at all mentioned in the question. At least make the answer complete, or let moewe answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same, had the same problem with LyX2.1.4 on Win7. Followed all the above no luck. Been here many times before with 'hidden' LyX stettings clobbering imported LaTeX :-(

Solution: `|Documents>Settings>PDF Properties>[Hyperlinks]Backreferences:[Off]`

Typesets exactly as it should :-)

Not quite, because the backlinks are disabled unless you select |Document>Settings>Bibliography>Processor: to work with bibLaTeX as stated in the previous comment by Torbjørn T.

> The universal solution would be for LyX to display all the
>   LaTeX settingings it 'applies in the background'. You can |View>Source Pane>[Preamble Only] but you still have to search for where it is set! B.T.W. if you only change the menu biber setting **LyX will NOT re-typeset** the document to show it works (LyX2.1.4-Win7). You have to type something! :-(

Comment: If you have a *specific* idea for how this information could be displayed, please describe in detail your idea in an enhancement request at http://www.lyx.org/trac . We are always open to new ideas if they are well-planned.

Comment: THX @scottkosty, Maybe program the equiv of my manual approach `|LyX|File>Export>latex(Plain)>` & make _preamble content_ auto. present in the `|LyX|Document>Settings...>[LaTeX Preamble]` (_greyed out_). Maybe a button **Show LyX generated Preamble**. Finding the 'hidden settings' would be **find-search**, if the user manual included the 'preamble content equivalent entry' against each setting. It would avoid days of turn-off experiences & reduce the LaTeX knowledge required to be effective.

Comment: Great ideas! Hope to see some of them pop up on http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: I did as you suggested Scott and it has already been rejected ;-( I am investigating the new LyX bug identified above at [link](http://lyx.475766.n2.nabble.com/LyX-Menu-Changes-Not-Automatically-Typeset-tc7580333.html)  It wasted days and undermined confidence in LyX/LaTeX until I realised what LyX is **not** doing.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Jethro. I hope that experience does not scare you away from making further bug reports/ enhancement requests. It is very important for LyX to have good user feedback. Thanks for your time and effort!